# How to make a Regex with a "/" that validates the words

Tags: java, regex

Currently I have a string like the following

```
/ location1711126633182 (A2) / location1711126650373 (A3) / location1711126758739/location1711126794800
```

I need to separate the `/` and leave a space between them, as it appears at the beginning of it. However, I am trying to use this Regex to identify the "/" but it does not work:

```
/[a-z0-9_\.-]/[a-z0-9_\.-]
```

I have to do it like this because random names can come in the middle of the `/`.

I have tried with this regex:

```java
String newString = actualString.replace("/[a-z0-9_\\.-]/[a-z0-9_\\.-]"," / ");
```

But I can't get it to look like this:

```
/ location1711126633182 (A2) / location1711126650373 (A3) / location1711126758739 / location1711126794800
```

Comment: In Java, you need `replaceAll` to enforce regex search and replace, not `replace`.

Comment: You most probably need `String newString = actualString.replaceAll("\\s*/\\s*"," / ").trim();`

Comment: *But I can't get it to look like this:* What lies below that comment appears to be no different than the input..?

Answer (score 0):

You can normalize whitespacing around the arithmetic operators using

```java
String newString = actualString.replaceAll("\\s*/\\s*"," / ").trim();
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qwtOTO/1).

Note that `.trim()` is necessary to remove added leading or trailing spaces.

**Details**

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `/` - a `/` char
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces.

See a [Java demo online](https://ideone.com/Ws0zwM):

```java
String actualString = "/ location1711126633182 (A2) / location1711126650373 (A3) / location1711126758739/location1711126794800";
String newString = actualString.replaceAll("\\s*/\\s*"," / ").trim();
System.out.println(newString); 
// => / location1711126633182 (A2) / location1711126650373 (A3) / location1711126758739 / location1711126794800
```